# Increase the size of / (root directory) when it is not using lvm

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, filesystem

I have an Ubuntu server with Filesystem as follows:

```
$ sudo df -h
Filesystem                                Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1                                 7.0G  6.2G  516M  93% /
udev                                      7.9G   12K  7.9G   1% /dev  
tmpfs                                     3.2G  300K  3.2G   1% /run
```

This server is on a virtual machine (VM). It is not using linux volume manager so I cannot use the best practice of adding a new disk partition (i.e. `sdb1`) and adding that to the group providing disk to `/`

What are the high level steps / procedure for increasing the disk allocated to `/`?  I do not want to go through the process of revising this server to use LVM, but is that my only option?

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
```

Comment: EOL Notice: Precise Pangolin (12.04) will be End of Life starting April 28, 2017 Best to update to newer version. I do not know VM, but it seems your VM is too small to start with.

Comment: Have a look here https://technology.amis.nl/2017/01/30/ubuntu-vm-virtualbox-increase-size-disk-make-smaller-exports-distribution/ if you don't have an vdi image, there are also tools to convert your image file. Make Backups before starting!

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe add new volume(s) and move `/var`, `/tmp` and/or `/usr`. It would take some work but you wouldn't need to reinstall the server using LVM.